# Is there something equivalent to django's managers in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, django-models, orm, sqlalchemy

I have some [SQLAlchemy models](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) (Declarative) and some queries to write like:

```
Mymodel.query.filter(Mymodel.myfield=='lambda')
```

Since I have to use the above query several times in my code I would like to do better than repeating it over and over. I know that in [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) you can do it by putting [managers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) in your models.

Is there something equivalent to django's managers in SQLAlchemy? Or maybe another way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For common queries I add a class method to a mapped (ORM) class. 
For example:

```
class User(object):

    @classmethod
    def get_by_username(cls, dbsession, username):
        return dbsession.query(cls).filter(cls.username==username).one()
```

The mapped class is essentially the manager.

Comment: fine, although not chainable ;(

Answer (score 1):

What I end up doing is creating manager classes. I only implement instance methods on the SA object and wrap anything that fetches/generates queries for lists/etc of model instances on the Mgr class instead.

```
class MyModelMgr(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_something(param):
        return MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.somefield==param).all()

class MyModel(Base):
    ........
```